# color some parts of text based o given characters flutter

Tags: flutter

how can I implement something like this.
[image]

I want to change color of the given characters in the search bar in the items down bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that depends on what's the data source and how you would handle white spaces.
A quick work around.

```
String search;

TextStyle positiveColorStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
TextStyle negativeColorStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.black);


TextSpan searchMatch(String match) {
  if (search == null || search == "")
    return TextSpan(text: match, style: negativeColorStyle);
  var refinedMatch = match.toLowerCase();
  var refinedSearch = search.toLowerCase();
  if (refinedMatch.contains(refinedSearch)) {
    if (refinedMatch.substring(0, refinedSearch.length) == refinedSearch) {
      return TextSpan(
        style: posRes,
        text: match.substring(0, refinedSearch.length),
        children: [
          searchMatch(
            match.substring(
              refinedSearch.length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else if (refinedMatch.length == refinedSearch.length) {
      return TextSpan(text: match, style: positiveColorStyle);
    } else {
      return TextSpan(
        style: negativeColorStyle,
        text: match.substring(
          0,
          refinedMatch.indexOf(refinedSearch),
        ),
        children: [
          searchMatch(
            match.substring(
              refinedMatch.indexOf(refinedSearch),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  } else if (!refinedMatch.contains(refinedSearch)) {
    return TextSpan(text: match, style: negativeColorStyle);
  }
  return TextSpan(
    text: match.substring(0, refinedMatch.indexOf(refinedSearch)),
    style: negativeColorStyle,
    children: [
      searchMatch(match.substring(refinedMatch.indexOf(refinedSearch)))
    ],
  );
}
```

Then call the method and pass the searched text as parameter:

Credit: https://medium.com/@nogadev/highlight-search-results-in-flutter-66f03974ddec

Answer (score 1):

You should cut your String in two parts. With a substring for example:

```
String str = "Dolania Travel"
String firstPart = str.substring(0, 2);
String secondPart = str.substring(2, str.length);
```

And use `RichText`

Example :

```
RichText(
       text: TextSpan(style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
       children: [
           TextSpan(
               text: firstPart,
               style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
           ),
           TextSpan(
               text: secondPart,
           ),
       ]
),
```

Comment: This only works when the given characters are at the start of the Text right?

Comment: You can color any part of a text.
you can add a third one to the textspan list.
FirstPart, SecondPart and ThirdPart. And you apply the color on the part you want (Left, right or center)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along these lines. I didn't test this, so there might be some indexes wrong, but this general idea should work.

```
    Widget createText(String name) {
      final _stringToMatch = controller.text;
      if (!name.toLowerCase().contains(_stringToMatch)) {
        return Text(name);
      }
      final _start = name
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(_stringToMatch); // gives index where match starts
      final _end =
          _start + _stringToMatch.length - 1; // gives index where match ends
      final _customText = TextSpan(
          text: name.substring(_start, _end),
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(
                color: Colors.red,
              ));

      return RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: '',
          style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
          children: <TextSpan>[
            if (_start == 0) _customText,
            TextSpan(text: name.substring(0, _start)),
            if (_start != 0) _customText,
            if (_end != name.length - 1)
              TextSpan(text: name.substring(_end, name.length)),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    names.map((name) {
      return createText(name);
    });
```